SSRS report column with a clickable link that displays a table by passing the clicked value in the column
I have an SSRS report with Total forms per year represented as Chart, what I need is, year to be a clickable link column (if it is not then also it is fine but if it is shown as link it looks good for users to click on it), but when user clicks on a year column, it opens a table in which all the orders for that year would be displayed and when we click again the table disappears, I have both the chart & table in the picture below, can somebody please help me how can I extend my report that way either with Table or with Sub Report. When a particular year is clicked in the Chart, the year should be passed as a parameter to the Tables Dataset Query and there are 2 datasets for main report & table or sub report, is it possible? Or how else can I achieve the above requirement when clicked shows orders for that year. Any help suggestion would be greatly helpful, thank you so much.


You can't do this as far as I know, the chart series and/or axis labels do not have an Action property. The closest you could get it to list the distinct years under the chart and set the action to reopen the report passing in the year as a parameter. You would have to set a default value for the parameter for when the report is initially opened and decide how you want to handle it (e.g. set it to 0 and apply no filter to the table datasets etc.)
